# Do compilers optimize if-statements for static values in c++

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, c++11

I'm working on a generic library class for a collage assignment, and it is very important that the code runs as efficient as possible, that is if we can reduce an if-statement we should do it.

I have the following code which is needed to initialize an array if it is a fundamental type such as double or int.

```
T b[dim];
if(std::is_fundemental::<T>::value) 
{ 
    memset(b, 0, dim*sizeof(T));
}
```

Now the question is whether this check is optimized out, such that it does not make a runtime check, or do i need to create a template for the initialization with a specialization for fundamental types?

I use G++ with C++11, but it should be able to run without the check on most, preferably all, compilers.

Comment: Note that if it is false, even if the compiler decides to erase the whole if-body, it has to be valid code. If this is not acceptable (i.e. if the body wouldn't compile if the expression is false), you have to use something like a template. This is not the case here, but it might be the case in some other scenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard doesn't address optimization, but I can't imagine
a compiler which wouldn't do this optimization.  But does it
really matter: you're talking about at most one or two machine
instructions, after which you call a function which does a lot
more.  And formally speaking, doesn't work except for integral
types.  (Not that I've ever heard of a machine where a double
with all 0 bits wasn't 0.0.)

But FWIW: `std::uninitialized_fill_n` should be at least as fast,
and you don't need the `if`, since it will work with all types.

Comment: It might influence the branch predictor of your cpu.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. The code is templated, which means that different instantiations will have different addresses, and therefore separate branch predictions.

Comment: @MSalters: branch prediction is implemented in rather different ways on different CPUs and manufacturers. On some a first step is hashing the address and then access a rather small table without resolving collisions. This would mean that other branches that hash into the same are influenced. Although this is likely rare, it *might* happen. Hence the *might*.

Comment: @PlasmaHH What might influence the branch predictor?  The advantage of `std::uninitialized_fill_n` is that it is instantiated for each type, so the compiler has more information to work with (e.g. buffer alignment, stride, etc.) and can generate better code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The if that is "about at most one or two machine instructions"

Answer (score 4):

Compile it with the asm listing enabled and take a look what compiler did in each case. The only way to know for sure what will happen.

P.S.
Different compilers might produce different results. But I guess you already know that.

Answer (score 3):

If you use compile time constants to enable code or not, you can also use specialised template functions and use SFINAE to enable the tamplate or not.This guarantee that only the needed functionality is compiled/linked in. This feature is independent from optimisation.

The following example give you an idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
void Do( T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = 0)
{
    cout << "Is fundamental" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void Do( T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value == false>::type* = 0)
{
    cout << "Is not fundamental" << endl;
}

class NonFuncdamental
{} nonFundamental;

int fundamental;

int main()
{
    Do( fundamental );
    Do( nonFundamental );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... and the only possibility to solve what I wrote in the comment on the question, i.e. when the "inactive" code wouldn't compile.